# using fleet with nodejs app deployment

Tags: node.js, deployment

I'm using node JS version 0.10.15.I want to use fleet to deploy my app on multiple servers,
first deploying on a test server followed by running a test and on success deploying it on another server.
After installing fleet when I type fleet or any of the fleet commands it gives error as--

/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
cat: /doc/commands: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was because of not having node installed on my ubuntu ,in my case,as a result /usr/bin/env was missing.
After fixing this, now it is working fine.